# Angular5 Http Interceptor with refresh_token

Tags: angular, refresh-token

I am trying to implement an access_token/refresh_token into my Http Interceptor in Angular5. The problem I have is I cannot do the call again after I get the refresh token.
So, when I get a 401 error (access_token expired), I get a new access_token using the refresh_token and everything works fine until here. Next, I should do the initial call again using the new access_token, so I am trying to do this with the second

```
return next.handle(req);
```

but this doesn't work. So when I click on the first time and the token is expired, the application successfully gets a new token and writes it into localStorage, but the initial call is not being made again. If I click again, the initial call is being made successfully (with the new access token which was stored properly on the previous click). It's like I cannot get out of the catch. Maybe I am doing a stupid mistake.

Bellow is my code.Please advise. Thanks!

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<any> {
    let access_token, refresh_token;
    if (localStorage.currentUser) {
        access_token = JSON.parse(localStorage.currentUser).access_token;
        refresh_token = JSON.parse(localStorage.currentUser).refresh_token;

        if(access_token){
            req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + access_token) });
        }
    }
    return next.handle(req)
        .catch((error, caught) => {
            if (this.isAuthError(error)) {
                return this._auth.getRefreshToken().map((resp) => {
                    let user = resp.json();
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                    access_token = JSON.parse(localStorage.currentUser).access_token;
                    req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + access_token) });
                    return next.handle(req);
                }); 
            } else {
                return Observable.throw(error);
            }
        })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use flatMap() instead of map() as shown below:

```
        ....
        if (this.isAuthError(error)) {
            return this._auth.getRefreshToken().flatMap((resp) => {
        ....                                    ^^^^^^^
                                                 here
```

Otherwise your solution looks good to me.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander! It seems `flatMap` did the trick. I also had to add `import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';` in order to use `flatMap`, but I believe this depends on the Angular version.
Many thanks for your help!

Comment: @decebal, please accept the answer if it worked. I'm glad I was able to help anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your intercept you need to set the headers.

```
if(access_token){
            req = req.clone({setHeaders: 
            {Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`}
        });
}
```

You'll need to do the same for the other token.

Comment: I already did that. Anyway, that works fine. The problem I have is with the code from the `catch`.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like:

```
if ( this._auth.isValidToken() )
  token = this._auth.getValidToken();
  req = this.addToken(req, this._auth.getToken());
  return next.handle(req);
}

// The getNewAccessToken is an observable
return this._auth.getNewAccessToken().pipe(switchMap(() => {
    const clone: HttpRequest<any> = this.addToken(req, this._auth.getToken());
    return next.handle(clone);
})).catch(error => {
  if ( error.error === 'invalid_token' ) { // if it fails to refresh the token
    // Redirect to Login, but you could also cache the url
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return Observable.throw('Login expired');

  }
  console.log(error);
  return Observable.throw(error);
});
```

The getNewAccessToken() function looks like is:

```
  public getNewAccessToken(): Observable<string>  {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded') // FIXME: Replace Encoded Base64 for a custom version
    .set('Authorization', 'Basic WQQPWEOIRUPOIUQ=');

    const params = new HttpParams().set('grant_type', 'refresh_token');
    const httpOptions = { headers: headers, params: params, withCredentials: true };

    return this.httpClient.post( this.oauthTokenUrl,  new FormData(), httpOptions )
      .map(success => {
        this.storeToken(success['access_token']);
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

The storeToken function:

```
  public storeToken(token: string) {
    this.jwtPayload = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(token);
    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
    this.subjectUser.next( { name: this.jwtPayload.name, email: this.jwtPayload.user_name } );
  }
```

Comment: So in `getNewAccessToken()` you retrieve the new `access_token`, but where do you use it to get the data you need from the API? I don't have problem getting a new token, my problem is I cannot make the initial HTTP request from inside the 'catch' after I get the new `access_token`. Also, on your code, you don't call `getNewAccessToken()` anywhere.

Comment: I fixed the getNewAccessToken() call.  The sequence is:

Comment: I fixed the getNewAccessToken() call at the example.  

I had problems using that too, because I didn't know very well how to work with the observable asynchronous calls.
The sequence is:
- check if the token is valid.  If it is valid, execute the original http request.  done.

- if the token is not valid, call a request for a new token, as an observable, and when you get the new token ( inside the .pipe(...) from observable ) add the token to the header and execute the original http request.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I managed to fix it by using `flatMap()` instead of 'map()`.